# backbone.js testing with Jasmine - setting up

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine

I read about testing backbone.js apps with Jasmine but still have a question about setting all up:

in my app, I have a code module called `userHttpClient` that is depend on other module called `httpClient` that's depend only on `jQuery`. It looks something like:

```
// userHttpClient.js
define(['jQuery','httpClient'], function( $ , httpClient ) {
    return {
            saveUser : function(name,password) {
            httpClient.post(....);
                }
...

// httpClient.js
define(['jQuery'], function( $ ) {
    return {
            post : function(...) {
            $.ajax(...);
               }
...
```

How can I make the jasmine tests .html page to load the modules above?
Should I include require.js and it's main.js file in the tests page and load the modules?

Or maybe I should write the tests specs files as backbone.js modules and run them?